# How do I allow the user to edit a single row in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, edit

The `JTable` should allow only a particular, selected row to be edited. The rest of the table should be in the non-editable mode. Upon clicking a an "Edit" button, it should ideally just take into consideration the row number and make it editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `isCellEditable()` in your table's [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable-int-int-) and return `true` for the desired row:

```
private static final int DESIRED_ROW = …;

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return row == DESIRED_ROW;
}
```